# Nested question in a sentence

Tags: punctuation, syntactic-analysis, question-mark

I was taught that any terminal punctuation marks end the sentence, however I have a particular sentence that I have been wrangling with:

**In order to answer the research question “Are bi-lingual individuals from China (a collectivist country) more likely to evaluate positively television advertisements that portray individualistic (Western) values than Chinese individuals with a low level of globalization?” a quantitative study will be conducted.**

Is this proper punctuation considering that the question is nested in quotation marks?

UPDATE: I am aware one could say...

A quantitative study will be conducted in order to answer our research question: “Are bi-lingual individuals from China (a collectivist country) more likely to evaluate positively television advertisements that portray individualistic (Western) values than Chinese individuals with a low level of globalization?”

Comment: A quantitative study will be conducted to answer the question about whether bi-lingual Chinese people are more likely to rate positively TV ads [or adverts] portraying individualistic (Western) values than monolingual Chinese people.//Normally, questions would not be nested as you did. Or you could say: A quantitative study etc. to answer the following question: "Do etc.[...]?".

Comment: Thanks for the addition of monolingual! But yea I'm sort of going with the updated version above, I was just wondering if its grammatically correct to do the bolded, not whether it is common practice.

Comment: The quoted material is in apposition to the noun phrase "the research question", so it seems that it should be set off somehow from the rest of the sentence, yet commas or dashes don't seem quite right.  I don't think there is any good way to punctuate your example.

Comment: I would suggest a comma after the question mark (both within quotes). I do that a lot and never get called out on it, so I think it's right. Check though

Comment: Colon: A quantitative study will be conducted to answer the question: "Put the queston here?". That is how to do this. Or indirect speech. But not embedding the question with quotation marks. It looks unprofessional.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would re-write the entire sentence so that it does not use a direct question, and also to remove some of the 'jargon'-type words (*e.g.*: Why use "individuals" when the shorter word "people" will do?). [Changes from original shown in *italics*.]

> A quantitative study will be conducted *to address* the question *of whether* bi-lingual *people* from China (a collectivist country) *are* more likely to *respond* positively *to* television advertisements *portraying* individualistic (Western) values than *are* Chinese *people* with a low level of globalization.

I still don't like "people with low level of globalization", especially as you appear to be contrasting that with "bi-lingual" people. Surely the comparison should be with "mono-lingual people", or "non-bi-lingual people", or simply "other Chinese people"?